# Electric field intensity problem

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have done two solutions regarding this problem. One with the unit direction and one with no direction (magnitude only.)

All of these solutions are an exact copy of how my professor answered a similar problem. In one solution there exists a definite amount of E while on another the value of E is zero. Looking at its illustration (again in reference to how my professor did it,) the solution with zero magnitude seems more likely to be correct. My professor did a really poor job on explaining how to solve this simple problems or maybe I am just stupid. Can you tell me if either one is correct or not?

Please excuse my poor use of proper notation. We were never taught how to do it properly.

Comment: Your first page has about the right resulting magnitudes, though I get: $$\left(-10.378\times 10^6\:\frac{N}{C}, -10.378\times 10^6\:\frac{N}{C}, +3.459\times 10^6\:\frac{N}{C}\right)$$

Comment: Why did you add the scalar parts in the second page, without including \$\hat{r}\$?

Comment: Why not exploit the symmetries to reduce your workload? Compute the field due to Q1 and Q3 first, and then the field of Q2 and Q4, and finally add them together. The possible symmetries were apparent to me with one glance at your diagram, which rendered the perspective view of the 3D plot sufficiently accurately for this to be so. Then I confirmed it by reading the coordinate values.

Comment: It's even easier. No symmetry needed. All of them have the same \$\vert\vec{r}\vert\$. And that's also needed to normalize \$\hat{r}\$, too. So there's a \$\vert\vec{r}\vert^3\$ in the denominator and it's the same for all of them. So it's just a matter of summing by the poducts of charge and by x, then by y, then by z. Apply a precomputed constant for each. Done.

Comment: @periblepsis slr sir, my prof, in her example, added the scalar parts that is why we added also the scalar parts. Is it wrong to do that?

Comment: The direction at which the vectors point to (like the principle applied in forces, whether positive for upward, negative for downward) is it not applicable in electric field intensity in general?

Comment: @Wolfram The scalar part has no direction to it. That's the job of \$\hat{r}\$. Is it the case that for the second page that you are supposed to be far enough away that they are effectively at the same distance and have similar \$\hat{r}\$? (Treatable as a lump charge?) All you did on the second page was, in effect, to add up all the charges. Why?

Comment: I added them all because that's how my prof computed for it. She did not explain further. What she said however is that "since we're getting just the magnitude at this point, we will do these (pertaining to her solution of adding just the magnitudes)".